# Ошибка в коде python - регистрация и проверка пользователя в БД в боте Telegram

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу при вводе команды боту в телеграм сделать регистрацию и занесение пользователя в БД (чтобы был уникальный айди, и нельзя было пройти анкету ещё раз). Перед этим он должен пройти небольшой опрос.
При этом когда я пытаюсь совместить одно с другим, происходит ошибка. Как решить проблему?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

name = ''
surname = ''
age = 0
bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Я - разговорный бот! Это тестовый бот, который пока что дублирует Ваши сообщения. Но вскоре он начнёт развиваться (наверное).")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['say'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "и шо ты хошь сказать?")

#@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
#def echo_all(message):
    #if message.text == 'Приветствую':
        #bot.reply_to(message, 'Привет')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['regbio'])
def send_welcome(message):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
      user_id = [message.chat.id]
      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES (?);", user_id)
      connect.commit()
      bot.reply_to(message, "Имя?")
      bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_name)
    else:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Такой пользователь уже существует.')
def reg_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text
    bot.reply_to(message, "Фамилия?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_surname)

def reg_surname(message):
    global surname
    surname = message.text
    bot.reply_to(message, "Скока лет?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_age)

def reg_age(message):
    global age
    age = message.text
    while age == 0:
      try:
          age == int(message.text)
      except Exception:
         bot.reply_to(message, "Эй, вводи цифрами!")
      break

    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes')
    keyboard.add(key_yes)
    key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no')
    keyboard.add(key_no)
    question = 'Тебе ' + str(age) + ' лет? И тебя зовут: ' + name + ' ' + surname + '?'
    bot.reply_to(message, text=question, reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Приятно познакомиться! Теперь запишу в БД!")

        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
         id INTEGER
         )""")

        connect.commit()

        people_id = message.chat.id
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = {people_id}")
        connect.commit()
    elif call.data == "no":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "На нет и суда нет. Чтобы повторно пройти процедуру регистрации, введи команду /regbio")
        #bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Привет! Давай познакомимся! Как тебя зовут?")
        #bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, reg_name)

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# проверка id пользователя в бд
def search_id_tlgrm(id_tlgrm):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT id_tlgrm FROM users WHERE id_tlgrm=?", (id_tlgrm,)).fetchone()
    if cursor is None:
        conn.close()
        return None
    else:
        conn.close()
        idt = cursor[0]
        return idt


# если id пользователя нет в бд - опрос
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    if search_id_tlgrm(message.chat.id):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Давно не виделись')
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваше имя?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_2)

# message.text будет содержать введённое на предыдущем шаге - имя
def start_2(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваша фамилия?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_3, message.text)

# message.text будет содержать введённое на предыдущем шаге - фамилию, а так же переданный третий аргумент - имя
def start_3(message, first):
    print(f'Ваше имя - {first}, фамилия - {message.text}')
```

не используйте `global`